# jButton array in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

I have this statement:

```
private JButton button_array [] = {
    jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, 
    jButton4, jButton5, jButton6, 
    jButton7, jButton8, jButton9
};
```

This does not seem to work though and gives me an error of "illegal forward reference".  How do I fix the statement?

Comment: You've got your array declared ***before*** the variables that it contains!

Answer (score 8):

Your error is not related with your syntax.
I guess your **jButton1 and other buttons** are declared after this statement.
Take them upper part of your array declaration. Errors will disappear hopefully.

**Legal:**

```
private JButton jButton1, jButton2;
private JButton button_array [] = {jButton1, jButton2};
```

This one is illegal and gives *"Illegal forward reference"* error.

```
private JButton button_array [] = {jButton1, jButton2};
private JButton jButton1, jButton2;
```

Comment: how would I get to compare my arrays?                               if (reset) {
    for (JButton button = button_array ) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("");
    }
    turn = false;
}

Comment: @mike157 if you have more of your code you'd like to add, please add it to the question statement using the 'edit' link underneath the tag boxes.

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton[] jBtns= {new JButton("1"),new JButton("2")};
```